# Axios request goes to catch block when it sees response status code in range of 400 and 500

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, mern

When server sends status code in range of 400 and 500 , axios skips the .then() block and directly goes to the catch block.
But when server sends anything with status code in the range of 200 axios accepts it.
This is the client side code.

```js
axios
  .post(`${API_URL}login/profile`, profile, {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
  .then((res) => {
    //console.log(res);
    if (!res.data.token) {
      alert(res.data.msg);
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token);
      props.history.push('/dashboard');
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

//handleLogin(profile);
```

This is the server side code

```js
Router.post('/login/profile', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('login req was made');

  //validating email
  const { msg, isValid } = LoginValidator(req.body);

  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(404).json({ msg });
  }
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  ProfileModel.findOne({ email })
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'user doe not exist' });
      }

      //compare passwords
      bcrypt
        .compare(password, user.password)
        .then((isMatch) => {
          if (!isMatch) {
            return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'please enter the correct password' });
          }

          const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, secrete, {
            expiresIn: 86400, //24 hrs
          });
          return res.status(200).send({ auth: true, token });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

Comment: You're starting a fact, and it seems reasonable to me that Axios treats HTTP errors as errors. But what's your question?

Comment: What I wanted to ask is , how to get rid of that .

Comment: you can place a catch block *before* your then block instead of after, so your then also gets called after the catch.

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you to try consoling error like in below snippet, you will going to get something out of it.

```js
console.log(err.message)
console.log(err.response)
console.log(err.request)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).